# How do I get an IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet key","spreadsheetname!J1:Y1") to autofill the range numbers?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I need to pull data from columns J-Y from a spreadsheet and concatenate them specifically for each horizontal row in those ranges into a single cell.

The best I can do is:

```
=CONCATENATE(IMPORTRANGE("123123123","SheetName!J1:Y1"))
```

That puts everything from a specific row into a specific cell. But the range will not auto update when I drag the lower-right box down the column.

How do I make it do that?

Answer (score 0):

does this works as you want if pasted into row 1 and dragged down:

=CONCATENATE(IMPORTRANGE("123123123","SheetName!J"&ROW()&":Y"&ROW()))